# Ошибка при выборке данных из базы данных,?

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Всем привет! Подключаюсь к базе и хочу получить данные. Ничего замудренного. Ниже код.

```
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$dblink = mysql_connect($server, $user, $password);
if($dblink)
    echo 'Соединение установлено.';
else
    die('Ошибка подключения к серверу баз данных.');

$database = 'ok';
$selected = mysql_select_db($database, $dblink);
if($selected)
echo ' Подключение к базе данных прошло успешно.';
else
die(' База данных не найдена или отсутствует доступ.');

$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("ok",$db);
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF-8");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table",$dblink);
if (!$query) echo "Не удалось выполнить запрос по причине: ".mysql_error();
```

Подключение к серверу Удачно. Подключение к базе удачно. Не работает правильно эта строчка:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table",$dblink);
```

Пишет следующую ошибку:

Не удалось выполнить запрос по причине: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table' at line 1

Куда копать?? Не могу понять!
Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: `table` - зарезервированное слово. Подозреваю, что оно не воспринимается как название таблицы (для этого надо обернуть его в backtick'и - \`\`, либо, еще лучше - переименовать таблицу).

Comment: Спасибо! Ответ верный, можете написать его как ответ и я поставлю +. Еще раз спасибо! Форум класс!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте для table добавить кавычки `table`

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`",$dblink);
```